# Scrollheight is not accurate for Nuxt app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, puppeteer

I have a very long (height) webpage and I'm using Puppeteer to get a PDF export of the page. It's about 30,000 px long.

I'm using document.documentElement.scrollHeight to try to determine dynamically the total height but it is returning 1018 when console.log and the PDF export is showing the same.

The 1018 is the viewport height so if I change the window it changes also.

Curious why this is?

The height is returning this way even in direct inspect > console.log and not using Puppeteer.

Any ideas why the height is not correct or how to fix this?

UPDATE:
This is my layout in nuxt

```
<template>
  <div
    id="my-app"
    ref="layout"
    class="flex flex-col h-screen overflow-hidden bg-gray-100 font-museo-sans"
  >
    <main class="overflow-y-auto">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-5 xl:rounded-lg xl:shadow-md">
        <Nuxt class="transition-opacity duration-200" />
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
```

The overflow-hidden and h-screen for some reason is necessary for my-app as if I remove it, the page does not allow for scroll.

I'm not quite understanding the behavior of this though. Why would overflow-hidden and setting a height to viewport allow the scrolling of the nuxt application?

In addition, I thought documentElement.scrollHeight returns overflow hidden but I guess it does not.

Comment: Are you sure your element isn't overflowing? Without seeing the inspector it's a bit hard to help!

Comment: I dont believe so but maybe it's something specific to Nuxt? documentElement.scrollHeight should include overflowing items no?

Comment: `scrollHeight` is the minimum height the viewport should have in order to show the entire element. So yes it's the height including the overflowing elements. This has nothing to deal with Nuxt, the native dom property are left untouched :)

Comment: Did a little more testing. I updated my original post with some code of the nuxt layout but if I remove "h-screen overflow-hidden" the scrolling from the app goes away. I'm not entirely sure why that is but I imagine there's something conflicting with the way it's reading the height?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem actually. I had to grab the scrollHeight of main and add an ID to main which is set to overflow-y. I'm still unsure why the outer wrapper my-app has a h-screen on it but I am guessing it's related to now nuxt works?

Comment: Was able to figure it out Hscreen and overflow hidden is for the outer wrapper so the header and nav, toast notifications, modals are all fixed. So setting an ID in main worked